# Rotating a shift each time a letter is read

Tags: java

Hey guys I am really struggling figuring one part of my program out. Right now it takes user input for a shift and shifts for encryption. However, when the user enters the shift, I want the program to shift further each time. So say the string passed in is just the word `The` and the shift value was one. T would move to U, then H would move to J and E to H. Essentially, each time one character is changed, the 'key' so to speak rotates further down the amount of the shift. So far this is what I have come up with and it's obviously not completely right but does compile and shift characters, just not with the added shift after each character. Thanks!

```
 public static String rotate(String userString, int shiftValue) {

        shiftValue = shiftValue % 26 + 26;
        StringBuilder encoded = new StringBuilder();
        for (char i : userUpper.toCharArray()) {
            if (Character.isLetter(i)) {
                if (Character.isUpperCase(i)) {
                    encoded.append((char) ('A' + (i - 'A' + shiftValue) % 26 ));
                } else {
                    encoded.append((char) ('a' + (i - 'a' + shiftValue) % 26 ));
                }
            } else {
                encoded.append(i);
            }
        }
        return encoded.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Did you step through it with a graphical (or other) debugger, and seen what happens in each step? There is probably some simple logic mistake which you will be able to spot that way.

Comment: If you want your shift value change with each character, you should change it in the `for` loop.

Answer (score 3):

You are not incrementing the shift after each iteration.

```
int amountShifted = 5;

for (char i : userUpper.toCharArray()) {
    if (Character.isLetter(i)) {
        if (Character.isUpperCase(i)) {
            encoded.append((char) ('A' + (i - 'A' + shiftValue) % 26 ));
        } else {
            encoded.append((char) ('a' + (i - 'a' + shiftValue) % 26 ));
        }
    } else {
        encoded.append(i);
    }

    shiftValue += amountShifted % 26; // increment the shiftValue
}
```

Comment: But that would only work if the shiftValue was 1, right? What if the user chose a shift of 5? Each time a letter was read and encrypted, the value for the next letter would be an extra 5. I would think I need an array that shifted and was refered to each time, but not really sure how to implement it in existing code? Thanks!

Comment: I edited the solution, it now supports different shifts (and also mods the amount shifted so it doesn't go out of bounds)

Comment: But this is assuming the user chose 5 as the amount to shift. shiftValue is holding their choice for the shift.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to increase your shift for every iteration of the `for` loop.

```
 public static String rotate(String userString, int shiftValue) {
     StringBuilder encoded = new StringBuilder();
     int myShift = shiftValue % 26 + 26;
     for (char i : userString.toCharArray()) {
         if (Character.isLetter(i)) {
             if (Character.isUpperCase(i)) {
                 encoded.append((char) ('A' + (i - 'A' + myShift) % 26 ));
             } else {
                 encoded.append((char) ('a' + (i - 'a' + myShift) % 26 ));
             }
         } else {
             encoded.append(i);
         }
         myShift = (myShift + shiftValue) % 26;
      }
      return encoded.toString();
  }
```

Second, `userUpper` is not defined. I changed it to `userString` in the code.

---

To let the user choose the direction that the text is shifted in, you can use an overloaded method.

```
public static String rotate(String userString, int shiftValue, String direction) {
    if (direction == "Left") {
        return rotate(userString, -shiftValue);
    }
    else if (direction == "Right") {
        return rotate(userString, shiftValue);
    }
    else {
        return "This is not a valid way to shift your message.";
    }
}
```

Note that the two methods have the same name, but they take different parameters. When you call the method, use the second one. Then you can specify which way you want to shift your message.

I have added more ways to do this in your new question, [Changing the direction of a caesar shift in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29829396/changing-the-direction-of-a-caesar-shift-in-java/29836851#29836851).

Comment: As my comment above states, wouldn't this only work if the shiftValue was one? What if the user entered 5 for the shift? Sorry was playing with something else with the userUpper, it was supposed to say userString, thanks!

Comment: I've edited my answer. Just increment by whatever shiftValue is. Note that I have change the `shiftValue` variable to `myShift`.

Comment: Awesome that is working! Only problem is with that code, the very first letter isn't being encrypted. Any Idea why? Also my last issue to resolve is the direction of the shift. I know I need to modify my method to accept a direction as a parameter. The user will choose Left or right and that will decide the direction. So would I just set a test condition for that variable passed in like `if direction == L` execute code, `else if` `(i + 'A' + myShift) % 26)`? Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Okay well I have my method now accepting the user input direction and have the loops that go through each instance, however I cannot figure out how to change the direction of the shift. I have tried using `-` instead of the `+` but I end up with strange characters. How would I get the myshift to go in the other direction? Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry. I have been busy for a while. Did you try replacing the `+` with `-` in the `encoded.append` line? That should should work. I have provided an alternative way to choose the direction in which to shift. This method calls the `rotate` method with `-shiftValue`. If it doesn't work, let me know.

Comment: It did not work, produced an output of `@@@@@@@@@! >>>>>>>>>>>>? VVVVV` which is not what I am expecting at all. That was using an input file with the alphabet only and two punctuations. Any idea why I'm getting this output? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This would be much simpler if you used String.charAt and an int for loop

```
    for (int i = 0; i < userString.length, i++) {
        if (Character.isLetter(i)) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(i)) {
                encoded.append((char) ('A' + (userString.charAt(i) - 'A' + i) % 26 ));
```

This won't work either, because it doesn't keep track of non-characters which aren't shifting. You can track the non-characters with another int, and adjust the `encoded.append(...` call to use that to get the right shift. I leave this for you as an exercise

Comment: What I have is working fine, minus the extra shift each time a letter is encrypted. Again if its the word 'The' T shifts one direction to 'U', then when H is read and encrypted, it shifts 2 positions to 'J' and etc. Each time a letter is read the shift automatically moves another position. Or if 2 is the shift, 'T' becomes 'V' then H would become L. Spaces and punctuation are encrypting fine by my method, just need to know how to get it to further shift itself each time. Thanks!