# Changing the direction of a caesar shift in Java

Tags: java

The user can choose to shift the letters either left or right by choosing 1 for left or 2 for right. Left is working fine, right is not. Right now it shows exactly the same loop, but I have played with changing all the `+` and `-` signs in different ways and I always end up getting strange characters. How can I get the program to shift the characters in the opposite direction? If the user types `Hi`, and the shift value is one and direction is right, the `H` should become `G` and the `i` should become `k`, as the amount to shift by should be increased by `shiftValue` before each letter. Also, the first letter currently is unaltered, which should not be the case.

```
public static String rotate(String userString, int shiftValue, int shiftDirection) {
    int myShift = 0;
    shiftValue = shiftValue % 26 + 26;
    StringBuilder encoded = new StringBuilder();
    if (shiftDirection == 1) {
        for (char i : userString.toCharArray()) {
            if (Character.isLetter(i)) {
                if (Character.isUpperCase(i)) {
                    encoded.append((char) ('A' + (i - 'A' + myShift) % 26));
                } else {
                    encoded.append((char) ('a' + (i - 'a' + myShift) % 26));
                }
            } else {
                encoded.append(i);
            }
            myShift = (myShift + shiftValue) % 26;
        }
    } else if (shiftDirection == 2) {
        for (char i : userString.toCharArray()) {
            if (Character.isLetter(i)) {
                if (Character.isUpperCase(i)) {
                    encoded.append((char) ('A' + (i - 'A' + myShift) % 26));
                } else {
                    encoded.append((char) ('a' + (i - 'a' + myShift) % 26));
                }
            } else {
                encoded.append(i);
            }
            myShift = (myShift - shiftValue) % 26;
        }
    }

    return encoded.toString();
}
```

Comment: Shifting backwards by 1 is the same as shifting forward by 25

Comment: How would I implement that? Thanks!

Comment: Just so we're on the same page: you know that what you've implemented here is not exactly a Caesar cipher, right? In a Caesar cipher, the shift is the same for all characters. What you've got here is a specific case of the Vignere cipher. (I don't know if it has its own name.) Also, are you sure `Hi` is supposed to become `Gk`? That would entail shifting the first letter left by one, and the second letter right by two. Did you mean `Ik` instead?

Comment: Interesting, did not know the difference in shifts. But yes, the shift I am using I want to be a little harder to break, so if the user chooses a shift of 2, it should rotate two places making `H` a `J` and then it would rotate two more places before encrypting `i` so it would then be a `m`. I know it's not really conventional but I want the shift the user chooses to rotate that many characters in the alphabet before each new letter is encrypted. Does anyone have any idea how to get it to go the other direction?

Answer (score 4):

In your code, you set `myShift` to 0 in the beginning and didn't change it when shifting your first letter. That is why your first letter is unaltered.

Do this before the actual rotation if you are shifting forward:

```
int myShift = shiftValue % 26 + 26;
```

---

I have answered your question already in your previous question, 
[Rotating a shift each time a letter is read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29826584/rotating-a-shift-each-time-a-letter-is-read/29826894#29826894).

You can use an overloaded method for your `rotate` method.

```
public static String rotate(String userString, int shiftValue, int shiftDirection) {
    if (shiftDirection == 1) {
        return rotate(userString, shiftValue);
    }
    else if (shiftDirection == 2) {
        return rotate(userString, -shiftValue);
    }
    else {
        return "This is not a valid way to shift your message.";
    }
}
```

The other `rotate` method would be the code that is repeated:

```
public static String rotate(String userString, int shiftValue) {
   StringBuilder encoded = new StringBuilder();
   int myShift = shiftValue % 26 + 26;
   for (char i : userString.toCharArray()) {
       if (Character.isLetter(i)) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(i)) {
                encoded.append((char) ('A' + (i - 'A' + myShift) % 26 ));
            } else {
                encoded.append((char) ('a' + (i - 'a' + myShift) % 26 ));
            }
        } else {
            encoded.append(i);
        }
        myShift = (myShift + shiftValue) % 26;
    }
    return encoded.toString();
}
```

Note that the two methods have the same name, but they take different parameters. When you call the method, use this one. Then you can specify which way you want to shift your message without worrying about changing the signs in your repeating code.

There are two other ways to make this work.

---

First, when `shiftDirection == 2`, you should replace

```
encoded.append((char) ('A' + (i - 'A' + myShift) % 26));
```

with

```
encoded.append((char) ('A' + (i - 'A' - myShift) % 26));
```

So the final for when `shiftDirection == 2` should be

```
for (char i : userString.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isLetter(i)) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(i)) {
                encoded.append((char) ('A' + (i - 'A' - myShift) % 26));
            } else {
                encoded.append((char) ('a' + (i - 'a' - myShift) % 26));
            }
        } else {
            encoded.append(i);
        }
        myShift = (myShift + shiftValue) % 26;
    }
```

---

Second, you can have the direction shift backwards by setting `myShift` to `-shiftValue` in the beginning and keep everything else the same. The complete code for when `shiftDirection == 2` should be

```
myShift = -shiftValue;
for (char i : userString.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isLetter(i)) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(i)) {
                encoded.append((char) ('A' + (i - 'A' + myShift) % 26));
            } else {
                encoded.append((char) ('a' + (i - 'a' + myShift) % 26));
            }
        } else {
            encoded.append(i);
        }
        myShift = (myShift - shiftValue) % 26;
    }
```

Comment: Doing any of these give me this kind of output: `@@@@@@@@@! >>>>>>>>>>>>? VVVVV` definitely not what I am expecting. Any idea why rotating this direction produces these symbols? Thanks so much for your help and explanation!

Comment: What did you use for `userString`?

Comment: I'm noticing a few letters are coming out funny... That's fixed by using `int myShift = shiftValue % 26 + 26;` instead of `int myShift = shiftValue % 26 ;` I didn't get such a weird result though. You said that you read from a file. Try the method with a string that you inputted first, just to make sure whether the problem is the method or what you read from your file.

Comment: I am getting a file from the user, then reading it in with a buffered reader scanner, then storing the info in the file into string. Then I sending that string to the rotate method. The string is making it there and displaying fine, and the rotate method when a user chooses 1 is working, however 2 still is not even when the `myShift = -shiftValue % 26 + 26;` I am really at a loss here. It is displaying the same symbols as above.

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong. It works fine for me. Consider posting a new question with examples, such as `When I input "Hello, World!", I get "@@33VVV"` or something like that.

Comment: Well, I am no longer getting the strange symbols, it is not however (when the direction is 2) outputting `ZZZZZZZZZ! XXXXXXXXXXXX? VVVVV` so I feel like I am getting closer. Does seeing that help you understand what my issue may be? Seems so strange, the letters are all the same, then I am not sure if it's the space or punctuation but then the letter switches..

Comment: So what *did* you input? Was it "ABCDEFGHI! JKLMNOPQRSTU? VWXYZ" with shift 1, direction 2?