# How to do a left Caesar shift in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I've figured out how to shift a string right using this block of code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < phraseArray.length; i++) {
  phraseArray[i] = (char) ((phraseArray[i] + add - (int)'a') % 26 + (int)'a'); 
}
```

This allows me to loop a character near the end of the alphabet (such as 'z') to a character near the beginning (such as 'a') if the shift is too big. However, I can't seem to do a shift to the *left* and have a character near the beginning loop to a character near the end. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the direction of a caesar shift in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29829396/changing-the-direction-of-a-caesar-shift-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this a caesar shift and you know the number of letters in the alphabet used(I asume it is 26 letters), all you have to do is add 26, because -1 "equals" 25 in this case. And of course % the "add" variable to prevent making it bigger than 26. Below is Your program with small change that shows what I mean:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    char[] phraseArray = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
    int add = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < phraseArray.length; i++) {
        if(add>=0) {
            phraseArray[i] = (char) ((phraseArray[i] + add - (int) 'a') % 26 + (int) 'a');
        }else{
            phraseArray[i] = (char) ((phraseArray[i] + (26+(add%26)) - (int) 'a') % 26 + (int) 'a');
        }
        System.out.println(phraseArray[i]);
    }

    return;
}
```

If you want it to always be done to the left for should look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < phraseArray.length; i++) {
        phraseArray[i] = (char) ((phraseArray[i] + (26+(-add%26)) - (int)     'a') % 26 + (int) 'a');
    System.out.println(phraseArray[i]);
}
```

full main below:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] abc = {2, 4, 8, 3};
    char[] phraseArray = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
    int add = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < phraseArray.length; i++) {
            phraseArray[i] = (char) ((phraseArray[i] + (26+(-add%26)) - (int) 'a') % 26 + (int) 'a');
        System.out.println(phraseArray[i]);
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: I can't use negative numbers as I'm using a key to decrypt the string (a = 1, b = 2, c = 3...), and whatever key the user inputs the program adds the characters together and does a shift based on the result.

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly, but 26 + any_value_minus_or_not%26 will always return positive value. Do you mean that you just want the shift to always be done to the left? If so just add - before add so it's like this: (26+(-add%26)). Edited the answer to show what I mean.

Comment: I meant that 'add' couldn't be a negative value, but your edited code seems to solve my problem. Thanks!